# loader.o file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, nasm

I am currently trying to build a super simple operating system.
I am using the tutorial [here](http://forum.codecall.net/blog/1797/entry-1944-making-an-operating-system-from-basic-using-c/), but then a problem popped. 
I look in the web, couldn't see anything might help.

I compiled `main.c` and `video.c` to .o files, everything worked when compiling.
I assembled the code in Nasm, using:

> nasm -f aout loader.asm -o loader.o
>   
>   The asm file content:
>
> ; Loader.asm
>   bits 32
>   extern main
>   global start
>   
>   start:
>    call main  ; Call our kernel's main() function
>    cli        ; Stop interrupts (thats another article?)
>    hlt        ; Stop all instructions
>   
>   Then, when I liked everything, error went off:
>   
>      $ ld -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel.bin loader.bin main.o video.o
>   loader.bin: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   
>   
>   Thanks in advance, Itay.

P.S. The "source" think is a bit crazy...

Comment: The problem is most likely that the linker expects object files in [ELF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and not [a.out format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I guess that to change that I have to do something else other than changing the extension to .ELF?

Comment: [Reading the manual might help](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.2).

Comment: Well, figured it out. Used 'nasm -hf' to see formats and replaced aout to elf32.
When trying to link it all up, it didn't work:
'loader.o: In function `start':
loader.asm:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `main'
main.o:main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__main'

<br>
when trying elfx32:
<br>
ld: loader.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
loader.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
<br>
When trying elf64:<br>
<br>
loader.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Using just elf refers to elf32, nothing else btw.